# How to handle the javascript decoding error?

Tags: htmlunit

When the code is implemented, some characters cannot be decoded. I am getting a bunch of question marks like ??. How can I fix this?

```
HtmlInput inputBox2 = (HtmlInput)currentPage.getHtmlElementById("classNo");
inputBox2.setValueAttribute("2016同學15");    
ScriptResult result = currentPage.executeJavaScript("javascript:Search(2)");
```

I found this in the compiler:    `ScriptResult[result=net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Undefined@24d7aac3 page=HtmlPage(http://www.xx.org/classNo=2016??15)@1330510442]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to use URL-encoding for some ASCII and all non ASCII characters.

e.g. space by %20

Here is a web site explaning the 
[HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).
You can also interactive encode strings there.

Your *"2016同學15"* would be encoded as:
*"2016%E5%90%8C%E5%AD%B815"*